# fetch url in javascript returns empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote this code for getting data from an API. but i just see *[]* on console.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvEdP.png)
I think i have to use `Promise` or `async/await`, but i don't know how i should to do.

Comment: WHY did you just replace the code with an image? That is bad.... You can not copy and paste from an image!

Comment: Because my code was not displayed correctly on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/await-react/#How_To_Use_Async_Await_in_React_an_example_with_Promises) is an example very similar to what you're doing:

```
// FILE: App.js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { data: [] };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=10`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => this.setState({ data: json }));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.state.data.map(el => (
            <li>
              {el.name}: {el.price_usd}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Async/Await is an alternative to using then's/promise chaining. In other words, you do not need async/await.

Answer (score 0):

When you output to the console, your fetch has not completed (i.e. hit the then()  callbacks).

If you would like to see the retrieved data, try putting the output inside the second then() callback after you set the table data to the return value.

Comment: I changed my code to this : `fetch(this.getLink(), {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(TableData => function() {
                console.log(TableData);
                this.setState({TableData})
            })
            .catch(error => console.debug(error));` But it didn't matter

Comment: @LastRemaining Close. Try putting it after this.setState(…)